# Jwt validation fails for OpenAM Forgerock in asp.net core using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, jwt

I have an asp.net core website using oicd authentication with OpenAM from ForgeRock. After successful login I get the following error from the JWT validation:

> SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation
> failed. Keys tried:
>
> 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey , KeyId:
> zhBofbZw+jkZZjXs28fGfzxZgM8='. Exceptions caught: ''. token:
> '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}.{"at_hash":"afZ0syNpXAt2va1x0E6OcA","sub":"XXXXX","auditTrackingId":"16cd7126-5743-4f65-8c8d-541c4446a9f9-14566","iss":"https://XXXXXXXX.com:443/openam/oauth2","tokenName":"id_token","nonce":"636172618434756181.MWFlOWRmYjUtNWRhNS00OTdmLWE2NTAtODVhMDQxYjRkY2U5ZTJmZTA0NzMtM2M0Yy00OGZmLTk1MDItMjZhNThjZTQ5NTBm","aud":"oidc-testapi-math","c_hash":"L0K_9odAoeKN0xl9n-_v-Q","org.forgerock.openidconnect.ops":"fb310afa-02a6-47ba-b604-d75e44389428","azp":"oidc-testapi-math","auth_time":1481665062,"realm":"/","exp":1481668675,"tokenType":"JWTToken","iat":1481665075}'.

(I removed the clear iss url and sub)

What is strange here – exceptions caught is empty. I wrote a little repro in a console program same error.

I found that **line 780** in **JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs (Version 5.1.0.0)** in method

`private bool ValidateSignature(byte[] encodedBytes, byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, string algorithm, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)`

it fails, why?

Comment: Same for me. I have tried RS256 and that throws a different but similar exception.